# Android Things Bundles <sub>.apk

Tags: android-things

What is allowed for the `<sub>.apk` in the android things bundle. For instance could I include the chrome browser apk as a `<sub>.apk` and have the `<main>.apk` call it? Or is it limited to application written specifically for android things?

I am just looking for clarification on the guidelines that any `<sub>.apk`'s should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't use any criteria to pre-determine whether an APK was developed specifically to work on Android Things or not, so the console doesn't limit the APKs you include in your bundle.

Any APK that is not hindered by the [behavior changes](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/index.html) of the platform will run on Android Things. If you install an APK that depends on some functionality not present on Android Things (like the Settings app or ContactsProvider) then you will run into problems, but we do not make these determinations for you ahead of time.